# How to notify the json object value change using Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

i know how to notify value change in object using the Object.defineProperty, but i want to know how to notify the json object value change ?

more on this

when  create a new instance for strore and set the value to price, notifyPriceChange will call ..

```
function store(){
    var price
    Object.defineProperty(this, "price", 
    {
        get : function(){
            return price;
        },
        set : function(newValue){

            price = newValue;
            notifyPriceChange();
        },

        enumerable : true,
        configurable : true
    });
}
```

i want to do same thing here.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"price":"120"}' );
obj.price = "John"
```

when i set the value to price means i want to notify . how to do this ?

Comment: and we want to know what you have tried

Comment: Which "JSON object" are you talking about? JSON is adata exchange format and as such a string in JavaScript. Do you want to notify the string? (whatever that means). It's not clear what you are trying to do and what you know. Please provide some example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference to JSON has no bearing on the problem.

Your issue is that you have an object `obj` with an existing property `price` and you would like to be able establish a call to a function should that value be changed.

Your store procedure can be adapted as follows:

```
function store () {
    var price;

    // if this.price exists, save its value and delete it
    if (this.hasOwnProperty ('price')) { 
      price = this.price;
      delete this.price;
    }

    // Now define the price property specifying the callback on change  
    Object.defineProperty (this, "price", {
        get : function(){
            return price;
        },
        set : function (newValue) {
            price = newValue;
            notifyPriceChange ();
        },

        enumerable : true,
        configurable : true
    });
}

// call as follows :

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ('{"price":"120"}');
store.apply (obj); // establish new price property with callback on change
obj.price = "John"
```

Essentially we remove the existing property, saving its value, then create the property witht he attributes we want.

Comment: What about this, when i have  more then one entity like this.       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"price":"120","name":"John","amount":"12"}' );

Comment: What exactly do you want in this case, that amount and price both be treated the same way?

Comment: yes, but the entries like price,amount are just one case. Those entries are provided by user side. So, they may also name it differently and also more entries like (quantity,number ,time). What should we do for those situations?